# How can I share messages globally across PHP classes?

Tags: php, oop

I'm building a small framework to bring myself back up to speed with PHP OOP. I want to be able to validate forms, and need a way to check an error bag across classes.

At first I was playing around with injecting the `MyApp` class into the `Validator` class, but there are going to be several sub classes and I can see this getting gross really fast, so I started playing with a `Base` class that would have methods and properties that could be shared across multiple classes. So if there's an error, the `Base` class could set it, and then the other classes could retrieve it.

I've been playing around with a simple implementation of this, and, while I'm not receiving any PHP errors, I'm also not able to pass the `error` from the `Validator` class back to the `MyApp` class so that it can be printed on the web page.

So my question is: why is `$this->setError($key, $key . ' is required')` in `Validator` not being passed back to `Base`, or if it is, why am I not able to get the value in `MyApp` and print it on the page?

Or is there a better way to globally handle messages for this scenario?

#### Base Class

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp;

class Base
{
    public array $errors = [];

    public function setError($key, $message): void
    {
        $this->errors[$key] = $message;
    }

    public function errors(): array
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

#### MyApp Class (public-facing)

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp;

class MyApp extends Base
{
    public Validator $validator;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->validator = new Validator;
    }

    public function text($key): string
    {
        return '<input type="text" name="' . $key . '" value="' . ($_POST[$key] ?? '') . '">';
    }

    public function request($key): string
    {
        return $this->validator->request($key);
    }
}
```

#### Validator Class

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp;

class Validator extends Base
{
    public function request($key): string
    {
        if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $this->setError($key, $key . ' is required');
        }

        return $_POST[$key];
    }
}
```

#### Web Form

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new MyApp\MyApp;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $app->request('name');

    var_dump($app->errors());
}
?>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <?= $app->text('name'); ?>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Reading from your first sentence I would say make a ErrorBag class and pass the entitiy through.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I had thought of a separate class as well, but wasn't sure how to implement it without having multiple dependencies injected into multiple classes. How do you recommend doing that?

Comment: That's no big deal and common practice with dependency injection. You also could go for an ErrorBag trait. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yup, I was actually leaning towards a trait as it just seems like it'll be a lot cleaner. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the fact, that your both classes share the same `Base-Class` doesn't mean there is any runtime-data shared between them. It's two different `Instances` of something, that extends Base.

What you could do, is make your `$errors` static. Static properties are shared across all Instances. You then can reference it by it's type name and not by any particular instance:

```
class Base
{
public static array $errors = [];

//function now could be static as well to outline that is has no relation to the instance itself.
public static function setError($key, $message): void
{
    //could also use self::errors here.
    Base::errors[$key] = $message;
}

public static function errors(): array
{
    //could also use self::errors here.
    return Base::errors;
}
}
```

from within any child of base, you now could use `parent::errors()` or `Base::errors()` to access the very same array.

But be aware, that sharing a property `accross threads` will cause issues due to concurrent access and/or modifications.

Also the question is here, if you really want to share errors throughout each and every Object - or if you just need it based on a USER-session?

for the later case, just have a look at `$_SESSION` which is an array, that can contain anything you want, accessible from everywhere from within the same Session.

Comment: I don't like static when you need to write tests, because it ends up like a singleton anti-pattern for OOP. To share data over threads I would go for a queue like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-get-queue.php

Comment: I think a `SESSION` would be overkill, as I'm mainly printing out form validation errors under each field, or at the top of the page. So the answer to your question is I'm sharing errors per `$app` instance: e.g.; `$app = new MyApp\MyApp;`

Comment: To clarify further: when a user submits the form and there is a validation error, the error bag is populated. The user corrects the errors and resubmits the form. If all goes well, no more errors stored in the bag and I'm done with it. I just need to see if there are errors for each field in different classes, such as when building the fields and validating the fields.

Comment: @timgavin well, it depends on your overall architecture. If you are instantiating `MyApp` only once per request and keep a reference on that, you could store the errors there, as a regular instance-property without any additional magic. If validation happens AFTER submit, keep in mind that's a new request, and therefore most likely a new instance of MyApp. Then, using `$_SESSION` would just be easy and not an overkill. That's what it is designed for: Persisting values for the session of an user, not just for the request.

Comment: @timgavin but yeah, for validation it shouldn't be required - as you only need to provide access to the errors within the same request (validation happens early I assume) and not necessarily persist it. If you are doing AJAX-based validation however, there is no way around a Session. (or say: it will be an unnecessary, hacky implementation)